# Remove trailing char if condition matches

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, text

Let's say I have a file with many URLs:

```
http://foo.com/abc_(Programming_Language)
http://example.com/test)
```

I'd like to remove the trailing `)` for each line in which there is no opening `(` using `sed` and/or `grep`.

The result file should look like this:

```
http://foo.com/abc_(Programming_Language)
http://example.com/test
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
sed '/(.*)/! s/)$//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below awk command

command

```
awk '$0 !~ /\(/{gsub(")","",$0);}1' filename
```

output

```
http://foo.com/abc_(Programming_Language)
http://example.com/test
```